# Installing elementary OS on a UEFI 32bit Baytrail

Tags: uefi

So I've been fiddling around with getting eOS on my Acer Aspire Switch ever since I got eOS on my main PC. It's been without success so far. Well, I can boot into the lice is using bootia32.efi but from there I still can't install the is as it tells me that grub64 is missing at the last stage of the install. Any way to fix this ?

Comment: I'd really like to know that aswell

Comment: Which version of elementary are you trying to install? AFAIK 32-bit EFI isn't supported in Freya, however I believe that this [bug was fixed in Loki](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1519733)?